# discord.js check if guild has a channel with a specific name, and if so, store that channels id to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js. Is there a way to check if a guild has a channel with a specific name, and if so, store that channels id to a variable? I am trying to make a command that logs it's actions to a channel with the name 'logs' if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) has a [`channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) property which returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [GuildChannels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). Using [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find), you can search for the channel by name by comparing [`Channel.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=name) in the predicate function. If a channel is found, you can read its [`id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=id) property to retrieve its Snowflake ID.

For example...

```js
const channel = /* Guild */.channels.find(c => c.name === 'some-name');
const id = channel ? channel.id : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

A [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) has a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels). A `Collection` has a [`.find(propOrFn)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method that lets you find an item based on one of their properties, in this example the [`.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=name) of a [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel).

Untested, but this should work:

```js
const channel = guild.channels.find(chan => chan.name === 'YOUR_NAME');
// channel.id
```

Comment: The "property/value" usage of `Collection.find()` is deprecated.

Comment: @slothiful It is? Why isn't it marked as deprecated in the docs and still used as an active example above using a function? I know `.findAll` is deprecated.

Comment: Only the specific usage of the method is. Passing in a predicate function is the expected way. Not sure why the docs don't mention it, but when using the older way, a DeprecationWarning is emitted.

Comment: @slothiful Updated, thanks for the heads up. Docs must not have been updated yet.